# Laptop automatically shut down at around 30%

Tags: laptop, battery, shutdown, power-management

I bought an Acer Swift SFX14-41G since 12/2021, which is pretty new laptop. The problem is it automatically shutdown at around 30%. After several times it shutdown like that, I have tried to calibrate the battery but it does not solve.

Why does it happen and how to fix it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it start the shutdown sequence and power off gracefully, or does it just turn off?

Comment: @gronostaj it depends on the lid is open or close. When it's open, the laptop popup message: "your battery is very low" then turn off. But when the lid is close at around 30%, the laptop just turn off.

Comment: I've had something similar. It was the battery controller that was messing up; the battery itself was fine. I would buy a battery at a place where I knew I could return it if it did not fix the problem. If that doesn't fix the problem, just return it.

Comment: @Gantendo sound like a good idea, I will try to do that.

Comment: In rare cases the battery reset pinhole trick works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfhgnxUJoZo & https://i.imgur.com/bd5Um3Z.png

Comment: If you suspect a hardware problem I wouldn't try fixing it myself - I'd get it fixed under the warranty. You don't want to risk breaking something when you've already paid for someone to take that risk. Check your power settings though, you may have 30% set as your low battery threshold.

Comment: Run the built-in hardware diagnostics for the Battery _(usually accessible via the BIOS/UEFI firmware settings or the BIOS/UEFI firmware boot menu)_, then contact Acer support